# Visual Studio Extension and Tools. Where is the licensing information

Tags: visual-studio

I am looking to use a tool in visual studio for my work.  I am looking all over the visual studio gallery site, and I can't find licensing information for any of the tools?

If you try and look at any of the tools on this page

[Visual Studio Galleries](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/)

No where on any of the pages, is any of the licensing information listed.  Where does one find this information?

**UPDATE**

I just took a look at a different extension, and I saw on the page there was licensing information for one application.  Not sure why there isn't licensing information for every one of those extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note the following information on the first page of the visual studio gallery web site

> Each contribution is licensed to you under a License Agreement by its owner, not Microsoft. Microsoft does not guarantee the contribution or purport to grant rights to it.

Second if the author provides a license, 1) clicking on the extension link 2) license link is provided will be above the description for the extension.

Comment: thanks.  After further review I saw that.  What if there is no licensing information for a specific extension?

Comment: based on the statement from Microsoft, if the owner does not supply a license I would assume that one does not exist, for questions contact the specific author.